# looking for fast query

Tags: mysql

users table

```
    id_name     |name
    1           |lubo
    2           |jano
    3           |elena
```

here user / score table

```
id_score    |id_name      |score      |month
1           |1            |0          |1
2           |2            |9          |1
3           |3            |0          |1
4           |1            |2          |2
5           |2            |5          |2
6           |3            |0          |2
7           |1            |0          |3
8           |2            |6          |3
9           |3            |0          |3
```

i want list of names with months where score is 0.
List should looks like this.

```
name        |months      
lubo        |1,3
jano        |
elena       |1,2,3
```

can i do this? i have about 1000 rows.

Comment: 1000 isn't very large in database terms. They are designed to cope with large numbers of records.
this sounds like a homework question. Have you written any sql already? You'll be wanting to use a SELECT statement

Answer (score 3):

The important steps are:

- WHERE score = 0 to select only the rows you are interested in.
- GROUP BY to group per id_name.
- JOIN to get the name.
- CONVERT to convert the integer values to a string.
- GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the result in each group.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(month, CHAR(8)) ORDER BY month) AS months
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON table2.id_name = table1.id_name
WHERE score = 0
GROUP BY table2.id_name
```

Note that many uses of GROUP_CONCAT are design errors. It is usually better to return one value per cell.

Update: to get *all* the names use an OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(month, CHAR(8)) ORDER BY month) AS months
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id_name = table1.id_name AND score = 0
GROUP BY table2.id_name
```

Comment: +1 - That's OK, but some people tend to execute queries like this and then use split(',') to retrieve the information. You can leave a note that it is not the best practice.

Comment: Thanks Petar Minchev, I've added a short note at the end.

Comment: mark,it works. Can i use it for about 100 000 rows in score table or there is other way for best performance?

Comment: @lubo: Yes, but make sure you use an index.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT N.name, S.month
  FROM scores S
  JOIN names N
    ON S.id_name = N.id_name
 WHERE S.score = 0
```

Then in your code you can combine the months by names as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like

```
SELECT name ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT month ORDER BY month SEPARATOR ",") AS months
FROM   users u LEFT JOIN scores s ON u.id_name = s.id_name     
       WHERE score = 0
GROUP BY name;
```

;